# is opendj replication can work on base DN which is not a backend?

Tags: replication, opendj

I am  not able enable replication on a base DN which is not a backend root.
ou=networkelements,o=networkdata

here o=networkdata is a backend ID.

Answer (score 0):

OpenDJ replication can only be configured at the top of a backend BaseDN (although a backend may have multiple distinct baseDNs).
If you have a directory tree with o=networkdata, and you only want to replicate a subpart of it (ou=networkelements,o=networkdata), you need to have that subtree be in a separate backend with a baseDN of "ou=networkelements,o=networkdata".